# How to manually override the automatic quotation of strings

Tags: c++, yaml, yaml-cpp

I am writing to a YAML file with jbeders/yaml-cpp and I am writing IP addresses to a file. When I write the wildcard IP "*" to the file, it automatically gets quoted (since '*' is a special character in YAML). But when I want to write the IP 10.0.1.1, it does not get quoted.

This is how I assign the node for the asterix:

```
ip_map["ip"] = "*";
```

This is how I assign the node for the numerical IP:

```
ip_map["ip"] = "10.0.0.1";
```

This is the resulting file that gets emitted with defaults (`yaml_out << ip_map;`)

```
ip: "*"
```

```
ip: 10.0.1.1
```

I have tried setting the emitter format option like this:

```
YAML::Emitter yaml_out;
yaml_out.SetStringFormat(YAML::DoubleQuoted);
```

... but this seems to double quote everything like this:

```
"ip": "*"
```

```
"ip": "10.0.1.1"
```

How do I consistently double quote all string values and not the keys or other numerical/boolean values?

EDIT:
I dumbed down the question a little and used literals instead of a variable.

Let's say I wanted instead to have a node like this:

fileA:

```
original_ip: "10.0.0.1"
```

Which I then read in with `doc = YAML::LoadFile("fileA");`. I then use the value from that file and try assign it to the original `ip_map["ip"]`, however I want to force double quotes around the IP address.

So the full snippet would look like this:

```
ip_map["ip"] = doc["original"].as<std::string>();
```

How do I force the ip_map node's assigned string value (`10.0.0.1`) to be emitted with double quotes?

Comment: You can use `"\"10.0.0.1\""` or `R"_("10.0.0.1")_"` for literals

Comment: I will mark this as an answer, but how would I be able to use a variable name instead of "10.0.0.1"?

Comment: Why does this matter?

Comment: If I wanted to write another node string value in double quotes like this `ip_map["ip"] = another_node["theIPStringKey"].as<std::string>();`

Comment: Please clarify: problem is not C++ literals, but how to force YAML library to write data in desired format? After writing yaml, reading from yaml (parsing result) should provide same value.

Comment: I am trying to force yaml-cpp to use the desired format

Comment: @Sam Why does YAML allow different quotation options? Because they offer different (partially subjective) readability trade-offs. Wanting to control this doesn’t really require justification.

Comment: Sure, @KonradRudolph -- but when read back in, you won't be able to tell the difference. The quoting in physical YAML files is completely immaterial, a compliant YAML parser will deal wioth it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik YAML, unlike JSON, is usually a *human-read* and *human-edited* format. In fact, that’s the only point of using YAML over JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should edit your question for conciseness, such as 'Using the yaml-cpp, how to serialize a map not quoting its keys but quoting its values?'.

To the point, you should manually iterate a map alternating string formats like the following.

```
yaml_out << YAML::BeginMap;
for (auto p : ip_map) {
    yaml_out << p.first;
    yaml_out.SetStringFormat(YAML::DoubleQuoted);
    yaml_out << p.second;
    yaml_out.SetStringFormat(YAML::Auto);
}
yaml_out << YAML::EndMap;
```